# System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path) does not read the html file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file

I want to read the html file.And for that I use ***System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)***.It can read all the html file but there is one file which  is not read through this function.

I have also used

***using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName)) {
   text = reader.ReadToEnd();*** But still there is same problem.

What is the reason can be there ? And for that what can be the solution ?  Or any other way to read the file ?

Comment: Maybe it's a binary file, and you need to use `ReadAllBytes` instead?

Comment: Please give some details. Does reading that file throw an exception? If not, how do you know it wasn't read completely?

Comment: When you open the file with notepad are you able to see anything?

Comment: @Henk Holterman.. Because I am doing like 
**String s;**
**s=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);**
And there is nothing in s.And if that file is opened with notepad there is all text in it.

Comment: @MadBoy..open the file with notepad we are able to see everything.

Comment: @Harikrishna: and what is s.Length?  If it contains a '\0' char you just might not see anything.

Comment: @Henk Holterman.. In the messagebox there is nothing for the length but one symbol is there that is <. But if I debug the code in the it looks like "<\0h\0t\0m\0l\0>\0<\0h\0e\0a\0d\0>\0\r\0\n\0<\0M\0E\0T\0A\0 \0h\0t\0t\0p\0-\0e\0q\0u\0i\0v\0=\0\"\0C\0o\0n\0t\0e\0n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I'll take a wild guess:

The file contains unicode sequences for extended chars and the diagnose is based on (mismatched) length.</strike>

> if I debug the code in the it looks
>   like
>   "<\0h\0t\0m\0l\0>\0<\0h\0e\0a\0d\0>\0\r\0\n\0<\0M\0E\0T\0A\0
>   \0h\0t\0t\0p\0-\0e\0q\0u\0i\0v\0=\0\"\0C\0o\0n\0t\0e\0n

Which is a valid beginning of a HTML file **except** for the very first char. The file is probably damaged by missing a unicode marker at the start. This damage was probably caused when it was written and is not (easy) repairable now.

You could try setting the WebClient.Encoding to UTF8 (and try a few ASCII as well).

Comment: @Henk Holterman..Only one file can be damaged but there are two files which displays like<\0h\0t\0m\0l\0>\0<\0h\0e\0a\0d\0>\0\r\0\n\0<\0M\0E\0T\0A\0 \0h\0t\0t\0p\0-\0e\0q\0u\0i\0v\0=\0\"\0C\0o\0n\0t\0e\0n.
Both of files can not be read.

Comment: Please use ReadAllBytes (it does work) and post the first 10 bytes as Hex.

Comment: And why can't the other file be damaged?

Comment: @Henk holterman..Thanks for the answer.It was the perfect answer that both of files were damaged.I had copied the html content of that file into new notepad file and saved that file as html file and now that new file with same html content can be read now.

Comment: @Henk holterman..But can any file be such that we can not read it due to security reason.That, is there any webpage that we can not read its html content because of security purpose or anything else.

Comment: @Harikrishna: No, this is not a security issue but something with Encoding and marker-bytes. Good old Notepad to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Does MsgBox shows anything? Any error? What does varText.Length show?

```
string varText = File.ReadAllText(varFile, Encoding.Default); 
MessageBox.Show(varFile + " Text: " + varText + " Lenght: " + varText.Length);
```

Verify in MessageBox that the path to file is correct, verify that the access rights from inside your application are the same as if you would be reading the file with notepad.

Comment: @MadBoy..In messagebox only the path is displayed nothing else for text or length only one other symbol is displayed with the path that is < .

Comment: Can you post the html file somewhere?

Comment: Also please check different Encoding (change Encoding.Default to something else).

Answer (score 0):

Came across this on google recently. The correct way to do it is via WebClient...

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String guestMsg = client.DownloadString("C:\\temp\\TheBarGuestDetailsEmail.htm");
```

File.ReadAllText will mess up the html when it's doing a read, and characters like £ or ' will get messed up.